# Site hosted on dropbox not using CSS

Tags: css, dropbox

I'm hosting a (very) small website on dropbox. I don't even have a domain name for it, I just need an easy way for my not so technology savvy teacher to access it and using an online service like wordpress or tumblr seemed like too much trouble and not as effective as I would like. I plan on putting it in my public folder and just sending her that link, something I've done in the past to show my friends websites I've made in class.

However, for some reason, CSS formatting isn't working. This is a problem I've noticed in the past but at the time wasn't important. I have it relatively linked in my head tag and it works when I pull up the files saved on my hard drive. Its only when I try to access it through dropbox do I notice this problem.

I've looked and it doesn't seem like anyone else has had this problem, I've only found multiple references to dropbox supporting CSS so I have no idea why this is happening.

This is the link in my code, and it's inside the head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/format.css" />
```

Any help would be much appreciated. ^^

EDIT: Here's the page, there's not much on it yet but there's suppossed to be background formatting behind the navigation links in the top.
https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/EPortfolio/WritingAndForum.html?w=947f0aa1

Comment: Can you post a link that doesn't work?  Probably easier to look at the source..

Comment: You would have to individually share each file and then update the link tag within each file to the full shared URL. In other words you can't relative link to something on Dropbox because once it's shared it has it's own private link. It would be much easier to get some kind of free hosting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give an example expanding on Cfreak's comment, you would need to individually share the CSS file, then reference it in the HTML like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1234567/cssfile.css">
```

Comment: Ahhh yeah that makes a lot of sense that it's no longer relative. Once I fixed that it seems to work fine now. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A much easier way (and more correct) is to put your stylesheet in a folder called css and then have a relative link to it with "./" It gets you out of the long url trouble.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
```

Comment: While this is a more conventional (not more "correct" - either approach is perfectly valid) way to point to the stylesheet, it will not work on DropBox because each file must be shared individually. Relative paths will not work.

Comment: Actually it does work.. I believe you should try it before telling it does not.. http://goo.gl/vkz5CH Here i made a sample html with link like the above pointing to the css stylesheet

Comment: @StefanosChrs, thanks didn't want to have to change all files

Comment: Your example link now tries to download the HTML instead of displaying it in the browser.  Do you know any workaround for that?

Comment: Hello @BenVoigt thanks for the notice. I found this announcement *Dropbox no longer renders HTML content in browser via Dropbox shared links. This means that if you’ve created a website that directly displays HTML content from your public folder, the website will no longer be accessible in the browser. However, the HTML content will remain in your Dropbox*